# MySQLi json encoded data parsed into Google Chart

Tags: php, javascript, json, mysqli

I can't figure out the correct way to move my MySQLi data from a correct json echo to the Google Chart code.

I query the data and echo out its results in json.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Count(e.song_id) 
AS song_count, c.show_id, e.show_id, DATE_FORMAT(c.show_date, '%Y') AS s_year
FROM tbl_song_shows e, tbl_shows c
WHERE e.song_id='{$sid}' AND c.show_id = e.show_id
GROUP BY s_year
ORDER BY s_year DESC");


//SHOW STATS TO GRAPH//

$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    /* define your DataTable columns here
     * each column gets its own array
     * syntax of the arrays is:
     * label => column label
     * type => data type of column (string, number, date, datetime, boolean)
     */
    // I assumed your first column is a "string" type
    // and your second column is a "number" type
    // but you can change them if they are not
    array('id' => 'Year','label' => 's_year', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('id' => 'value','label' => 'song_count', 'type' => 'number')

);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
$temp = array();
    // each column needs to have data inserted via the $temp array
    $temp[] = array('v' =>  $r['s_year']);    
$temp[] = array('v' =>  (int) $r['song_count']);

    // insert the temp array into $rows
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

// populate the table with rows of data
$table['rows'] = $rows;

// encode the table as JSON
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

// set up header; first two prevent IE from caching queries
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Content-type: application/json');

// return the JSON data
echo $jsonTable;
```

This returns:
{"cols":[{"id":"Year","label":"s_year","type":"string"},{"id":"value","label":"song_count","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"2013"},{"v":5}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012"},{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":"2005"},{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":"2003"},{"v":1}]}]}

If I just paste that into the Google Chart like this the Chart works fine.
But I don't want to hardcode the data in there I want to send the echoed data to the Javascript for Google Chart.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {




var jsonData = {"cols":[{"id":"Year","label":"s_year","type":"string"},{"id":"value","label":"song_count","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"2013"},{"v":5}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012"},{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":"2005"},{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":"2003"},{"v":1}]}]}



      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
     var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);


      var options = {
           title: 'Yearly Song Counts',
         chartArea:{left:40, width:850, height:250},
    legend: {position: 'none'},
colors:['#94B599'],
hAxis: {gridlines:{count:6}}
        };
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      // Do not forget to check your div ID
      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
```

Shouldnt I be able to do something like:

```
var jsonData = $jsonTable
```

Can anyone help me figure this out?

I also have a previous question: [MySQL Find previous date that a song was played](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324730/mysql-find-previous-date-that-a-song-was-played) that hasn't been answered, if anyone can help me answer either of these I'd be much appreciative. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. You just need to `echo` the variable inside the PHP context (`<?php ... ?>`)

```
var jsonData = <?php echo $jsonTable;  ?>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked however since I have a few queries open running from my database the Chart works now but any database code requesting data below the script no longer works. I'll have to figure out what's going on. I have the Google Chart Javascript in the header with the query above that so it can read $jsonTable.

Answer (score 0):

If your `<script>` block above is part of a .php scsript, then you can have PHP embed its output in the JS code, e.g.

```
<script>
    var jsonData = <?php echo json_encode($table); ?>;
    ...
</script>
```